# Perpendiculars to Tangent line lengths

Tags: geometry

> Line l is tangent to circle O at A. Let D be the foot of the perpendicular from A to chord BC. The perpendiculars from B and C to are drawn to l with feet at E and F respectively. If BE=6 and AD=8, what is CF?

I haven't made much progress on this problem. EABD and DAFC are cyclic, but nothing else is useful.Additionally Pop on E and F don't reveal anything yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let FC=6 and try to find BE(make no difference). Extend BC and EF to cross at G. We have:

$\triangle ADE ≈\triangle CFG ≈ \triangle BEG  $

⇒$\frac{FC}{AD}=\frac{CG}{AG}=\frac{6}{8}$

Also:

$\frac{FC}{EB}=\frac{CG}{BG}$

$AG^2=CG \times GB$

⇒ $\frac{AG^2}{CG^2}=\frac{GB}{CG}=\frac{64}{36}$

⇒ $\frac{FC}{EB}=\frac {36}{64}$

⇒ $EB=\frac {6\times 64}{36}\frac{64}{6}≈ 10.66$

Comment: Referring to your construction in my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Sirous diagram if angle at G is $\gamma$

by similar triangles obtained by noting that corrosponding hypotenuses are $GC,GA,GB$ 
$$ \frac{FC}{GC}= \frac{DA}{AG}= \frac{EB}{BG} = \tan \gamma $$

$$  (\frac{DA}{AG})^2=   \frac{EB}{BG} \cdot \frac{FC}{GC} = \tan ^2\gamma$$
By Circle property of segments product and tangent to circle squared drawn from G
$$ GA^2= GC\cdot GB $$

Note that these lengths are in *geometric progression.*

So we can cancel out the denominators leaving
$$DA^2= EB\cdot FC\rightarrow FC = DA^2/ EB =8^2/6 =10.6667 $$